# Javascript: Accessing functions within Anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, anonymous-function

[Using jQuery as suggested by Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers), I have wrapped my code in an anonymous function so that jQuery will not conflict with other javascript libraries:

```
(function($) {

    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut

})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that I want to split my code into two files: 1) main.js and 2) utility.js.

How can the main program (main.js) call functions within the other file (utility.js) when both are encapsulated?

**utility.js**

```
(function($) { 

function doSomething() {
    /* code here */
}

})(jQuery);
```

**main.js**

```
(function($) { 

$(document).ready(function(){
    doSomething();
}

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the below answers, I would look into [namespacing](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/)

Comment: Thanks for the read Tomanow. Will look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to return an object out of this ***utility.js***:

```js
(function($, win) {
  win.util = function(){
    this.doSomething = function() {
      $('pre').append('util.js');
    }
  };
})(jQuery, window);

(function($, $U) { // <----referred it with $U

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $U.doSomething();
  });

})(jQuery, new util()); //<----pass the util object here.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

---

Actually i like the way to use it in OOJS way. Try creating a constructor and pass a new object.

Comment: It's working.  Thanks.  Got some additional questions though.  Both your's and pablochan's code below works.  Coming from a PHP background, why do you have to assign util as a function and not just an object as what pablochan did, which seems to be more straightforward?  Is this just preference or is this a safer or more extensible method?  Also, why do we need 'new' and not just 'window.util' which throws an error? pablochan code works without using new().  Thanks again!

Comment: @alds this is just as same as the other answer. The thing here is that you have passed an object as a reference. And the keyword `this` is used as a public property which is globally available. But the other answer used as a function instead which is also good but using as an object is much better way.

Comment: Thanks Jai.  Had to read up to understand all these differences

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to assign all functions in `utility.js` to some global object. Assuming your code works in the browser you could do something like this:

**utility.js**

```
(function($, context) { 

context.Utility = {
    doSomething: function() {
        /* code here */
    }
};

})(jQuery, window);
```

**main.js**

```
(function($, Utility) { 

$(document).ready(function(){
    Utility.doSomething();
}

})(jQuery, Utility);
```

A more general solution would be to use asynchronous module loading (http://requirejs.org/) or a tool like [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) to manage modules in your application.

Comment: It's working. Thanks @pablochan.  Also for mentioning require.js and JSPM.  I had to read over them sometime as they are new to me.